# how do I trigger fancybox gallery with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Im testing out fancybox, looks quite a nice little library for galleries and loading in content. I've got the following code below kind of working, however I need it to trigger off the gallery as soon as I click on an item with the lightbox class. The code below loads content from gallery.htm into the content div and then when I click on a thumbnail image from my content div it launces fancybox. What I am trying to do is on one click load my dynamic content and launch fancy box, anyone advise me please?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.lightbox').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var url = "gallery.htm";
    $('#content').load(url, function(data, stat, req){
        $("a.lightbox").fancybox();
    });
})
```

});

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you would need two selectors:

1). one to load the gallery thumbnails into the page using the `.load()` method, e.g. `loadGallery`:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="loadGallery">add dynamic gallery thumbnails</a>
```

2). another to bind elements to fancybox, e.g. `lightbox`. All the elements within the file "*gallery.htm*" should have then such `class` like:

```
<a class="lightbox" rel="gallery1" href="images/01.jpg"><img src="images/01t.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="lightbox" rel="gallery1" href="images/02.jpg"><img src="images/02t.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="lightbox" rel="gallery1" href="images/03.jpg"><img src="images/03t.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Then bind those elements (in your main page) to fancybox with one script and load the gallery thumbnails into the page and fire the  fancybox gallery within the same `click`, with another like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // bind elements to fancybox
 $(".lightbox").fancybox();
 // load thumbnails and fire fancybox gallery
 $('.loadGallery').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = "gallery.htm";
  $('#content').load(url, function(data, stat, req){
   $(".lightbox").eq(0).trigger("click");
  }); // load
  $(this).remove(); // you may remove the selector loadGallery after loading the thumbnails
 }); // on
}); // ready
```

Notice that we are using `.on()` instead of [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) since the second has been deprecated. The `.on()` method requires jQuery 1.7+ though.

Also notice that we used `.eq(0)` to start the gallery from the first item, otherwise the gallery will start from the last element appended to the document.

**UPDATE** : See it working here [DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/loadGalleryDynamically_11jun12.html)

Comment: Hi JFK, tried this, but it says requested content could not be loaded.I've got an alert to see what is loading into #content, and the indeed the image tags are all in their with the correct rel attribute. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I've managed to get something working with your code, however it does not work in FireFox. Anychance you can help me with this please? Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000279/fancybox-working-fine-in-i-e-but-not-in-firefox

Comment: I don't think it was a good idea to open a new question since things can get messy (we could have sorted everything within this one.) In your other question you are using the same selector when I advised you to use two different ones.

Comment: Hi JFK, apologies, thought I had the other code cracked at work until I fired off FF - and it all messed up. Tried at home, and I.E doesnt work nor does FF and Chrome. So I think Im going to go back to basics and work with this code, also reply on the other thread so I dont wast anyones time. Ok, redone my page with your code, it looks as though the content is getting loaded in my page, however when fancybox fires up, it comes up with requested content cannot be loaded please try again.

Comment: See my UPDATE in the answer, I added a DEMO so you can compare the code.

Comment: Thank you, you are a star. Had the code exactly as you, however I had a testlink at the bottom of the page with the fancybox class which I didnt remove, hadnt realised that would make a difference, always helps going back to basics :) Thanks once again for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0):

I would make Aajax request which would return JSON response containing gallery items. Then I would open fancybox manually (e.g. $.fancybox.open( response ); where response would be like [{href: ''},{href:''}])

Comment: Hi Janis, I solved my original issue with JFK's solution. However I have come across another plugin I might like to use for something else but requires json response. I know how to get responses back as html, but how so I convert them into json to use with these plugins? Is there a library I need to access or something else?

Comment: If your response is JSON-encoded data (e.g. using json_encode in php) then you can do like - $.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: function( data ) { $.fancybox.open( data ); }
});

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise there was a library like JSON-encoded I could tap in.Ive found an equivalent for asp :) - will try and figure out how to use it :)