# how to use fancybox with dynamically loaded data via ajax

Tags: ajax, fancybox

I am using `fancybox` 2.x for displaying data, I have loaded some data through `ajax` into a div , now from ajax call data is coming like this

```
<a href="sample.php" class="fancy" >sample</a>
```

in head i have fancybox code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".fancy").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'fadein',
        'transitionOut' :   'fadeout',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'width'         :   260, 
        'height'        :   260, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false,
        'type'          :   'iframe'            
    });

});
```

but this is not working, if i write

```
<a href="sample.php" class="fancy" >sample</a>
```

the same code in document , it works, please tell me how i can use `fancybox` with dynamically loaded data via `ajax` ... waiting for solution.

Comment: are you sure you are using fancybox v2.x? because the options in your script are for fancybox v1.3.4

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I trigger fancybox gallery with dynamic content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986953/how-do-i-trigger-fancybox-gallery-with-dynamic-content)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this line:

```
<a href="sample.php" class="fancy" >sample</a>
```

does not exist when the page is loaded. But it is loaded via another ajax call later. If that is the case, your javascript code will not attach to the element.

The code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

only runs once the DOM loads.

You need to either call the fancybox function in a callback of the ajax function (see Complete in the [jQuery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)),
...
Or do something like what this blog post does: [Adding Fancybox to Dynamically Loaded Content](http://www.graphicsunplugged.com/2011/05/adding-fancybox-to-dynamically-loaded-content/)

Comment: `... via another ajax call later. If that is the case, your javascript code will not attach to the element.` if using fancybox v2.x, it will, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10988034/1055987